# how many 'text' column a table could have in mysql? I have this error “Row size too large (> 8126).”

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a application which is kinda complex to explain how it works. But this is the situation I'm in,

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FIELD1 (TEXT) FIELD2(TEXT) FIELD3(TEXT) .........................FIELD70(TEXT)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

POSSIBLE DATA SIZE FOR A SINGLE FIELD: around 500 characters.

I have around 20 tables in a single database like this.

I know it's too bad idea to have this much column in a single table. But I have to go with this since It's went too far and can not modify number of columns.

**Now I got some error like**, "Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline."

WHAT I HAVE TRIED:

- I altered the table as ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED. = didn't work out
- I altered the table as ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC. = didn't work out
- innodb_file_format = Barracuda = didn't work out
- I altered the column to VARCHAR(500) = didn't work out
- I altered the column to TEXT,BLOG,MEDIUMBLOG = didn't work out

What could be the actual error? I've seen plenty of the answers for this problem bur they are telling these above methods that I've tried and failed. **PLEASE HELP ME TO SOLVE THIS**

Comment: Are you getting the error when creating the table, when altering the table structure, or when inserting/manipulating rows? If the table created OK provide the results of running `SHOW CREATE STATUS YourTableName` to show what you currently have including what storage engine the table is using. Things like this will vary by storage type.

Comment: Have you dropped and recreated the table after switching the innodb file format? Have you also used innodb_file_per_table too?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the row size limit for InnoDB tables, in this links you can find some approaches to solve this:

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/04/07/innodb-row-size-limitation/ 
[InnoDB create table error: "Row size too large"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/innodb-create-table-error-row-size-too-large)